# Is the characteristic function of a multivariate normal distribution a real analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, complex-analysis

The characteristic function of a multivariate normal distribution with mean $\mu \in \mathbb R^n$ and covariance $\Sigma \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
e^{it^T\mu - \frac{1}{2}t^T\Sigma t}.
\end{align*}
I am lacking some basics here and would like to know whether or not this is a real analytic function, i.e. agrees with its taylor series in a neighborhood of every point $t \in \mathbb R^n$.

I am not so familiar with Taylor expansions in higher dimensions and real analyticity.

Comment: I believe the answer is yes since the mgf exists for every value. Also analytic requires this to hold for every t in the complex i think.

Comment: @Lost1 The question says *real-analytic*.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. I see. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a real-analytic function. (It is complex-analytic too; it's an entire function on $\mathbb C^n$). Indeed,

1. Polynomials are real-analytic
2. Exponential function is real-analytic
3. *Analytic functions are closed under the most common operations, namely: linear combinations, products and compositions of real analytic functions remain real analytic.* [Source](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Real_analytic_function)

The  point of 3 is that one can plug a power series into another power series, work out the coefficients, and everything will converge. Terms can be rearranged at will, because power series converge in a very robust way within the interval   of convergence.